# Decompose Logstash json message into fields

Tags: logstash

It have a logfile that stores event with a timestamp and a json message. For example:

> timestamp {"foo": 12, "bar": 13}

I would like to decompose the keys (foo and bar) in the json part into fields in the Logstash output.

I'm aware that I can set the format field in the Logstash file filter to json_event but in that case I have to include the timestamp in json. There is also a json filter, but that adds a single field with the complete json data structure, instead of using the keys.

Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: You definetely should give a try to @Nikhil-S' answer. Alternatively you can also use a kv filter http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.1/filters/kv

Answer (score 16):

Try the latest logstash 1.2.1 and use codec value to parse json events directly.

```
input {
    file {
        type => "tweetfile"
        path => ["/home/nikhil/temp/feed/*.txt"]
        codec => "json"
    }
}
filter{
    json{
        source => "message"
        target => "tweet"
    }
}
output {
    stdout { }
    elasticsearch { embedded => true }
}
```

Comment: What happens with the timestamp field when this is done?

Answer (score 10):

I've done this with the following config:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => ["message", "\[%{WORD}:%{LOGLEVEL}\] %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:tstamp} :: %{GREEDYDATA:msg}"]
  }
  date {
    match => [ "tstamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
  }
  json {
    source => "msg"
  }
}
```

By the way, this is a config for the new version 1.2.0.

In version 1.1.13 you need to include a **target** on the json filter and the reference for **message** in the ***grok*** filter is **@message**.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use plain [Grok filters](http://logstash.net/docs/1.1.13/filters/grok) (regex style filters/patterns) and assign the matched value into a variable for easy organization, filtering and searching.

An example:

```
((?<foo_identifier>(\"foo\"))):((?<foo_variable_value>(\d+,)))
```

Something along those lines.

Use the [GrokDebugger](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to help out if you get stuck on the syntax, patterns and things you think should be matching but aren't.

Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: I considered that option, but was hoping that it was straightforward to parse a json structure and have the keys automatically translated to field names.

Answer (score -4):

your JSON is wrong `{"foo": 12, "bar" 13}`

should be:

`{"foo": 12, "bar": 13}`